# Linking mvc razor checkbox to razor textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**tl;dr I want to save the value of a textbox to the model ONLY IF the checkbox is checked.**

First off, I know my code is very messy. I've been trying to improvise my code off of another stack overflow question so it is first and foremost wrong.  What I am trying to do is I have these restrictions to an event, some are bool and some are numbers. For example, no smoking is a bool, but minimum age is a number. These are optional though, the user doesn't have to set any. So I want to have a checkbox saying that they want the restriction but to also save the value to the model.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ageLowCapCB" 
    @(((Model.currentRestrictions.AgeLowCap != null) && 
      (Model.currentRestrictions.AgeLowCap != 0)) ? "checked = 'checked'" : "") 
    /> 
    Low Age Limit
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.currentRestrictions.AgeLowCap, new {id = "ageLowCap"})
</p>
```

and the script/jquery for this I have is:

```
$("#ageLowCapCB").click(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

    $("#ageLowCap").val(isChecked ? /*I don't know what to put here*/);
});
```

The question I pulled this from was using values of "T" or "F" for true and false so it was easy for them to fill in the comment section putting "T" : "F" and that was it. But I need to pull the value of the text box and set it to the value of Model.currentRestrictions.AgeLowCap.  Does anyone have any good ideas on what to do in a weird situation like this?

Comment: Firstly, whoever downvoted you should have left a comment - otherwise it's a completely pointless exercise. grrrr. Having said that, I kind of empathise because the question is impregnable  - can you summarise what you want to happen?

Comment: I want the checkbox to define whether or not the want a cap on the minimum age. But if they do, I want it to save an integer value from the textbox. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. I would just do this in the controller - get the checkbox status, and if checked, save the textbox value. That seems too simple, apologies if I've missed something fundamental.

Comment: @BrentonHawley why not send that checkbox value along to other stuff and server-side you can determine and set whatever you want based on all these values?

Comment: You would be better off using a view model with a property for the `bool` and then adding a `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute - eg [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) - so you get client and server validation out of the box and no need for the script.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is on way of passing your javascript values to c# view model. However there is some workarounds. You can create action which will accept whatever you want to pass from javascript to c# and then when you need to pass that value(s), that can be done by making ajax request to that action and in that action you can persist that value(s). From there you have many options like in database, session and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear to my understanding. What I understand is if Checkbox is checked display textbox which accepts integer value. All these are model fields.

Approach 1: Write a JavaScript function to detect if Checkbox checked attr is true, Display textbox to accept input from user; Write function for textbox to accept only integers. Onkeypress you can call that function.

Approach 2: If you do not have to take integer value from user in textbox, then on post validate if checkbox is checked and assign value to integer textbox if it is true.

-Thanks